# "index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4"

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, indexing

When I try to run it I get error **index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4** for the line defining **x2**. Not sure why I'm getting error because the matlab equivalent works fine. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Code bellow:

```
NELEM = 5
con = np.array([[1,3], [1,2], [1,4], [2,3], [2,4]])
node = np.array([[1, 12, 0], [2, 8, 10], [3, 0, 10], [4, 24, 10]])

for a in range(0, NELEM):
    n1 = con[a,0]
    n2 = con[a,1]

    x1 = node[n1, 1]
    x2 = node[n2, 1]
    dx = x2 - x1
```

Comment: indices in python starts at 0, so if a array has length 4 you cannot access to index 4, the last will be 3!! modify your con to go from 0 to 3

Comment: Presumably this is due to the element `[1,4]` in `con`.  `n2` will be 4 in this case, so `x2 = node[n2, 1]` is trying to access `node[4, 1]` which is out of bounds.

Comment: @JohnGordon I didn't read closely enough. Good explanation. Either way, this is a question of basic [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: It works in Matlab because arrays there start from index 1.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, the node array has indices `0` to `3`, while the `con` array has an element `[1,4]` which is used to index `node`, the `4` here is clearly out of bounds. You should subtract `1` from the `con` array for proper indexing. Note that MATLAB arrays start at index `1`, so the code works without issues.

```
import numpy as np

NELEM = 5
con = np.array([[1,3], [1,2], [1,4], [2,3], [2,4]])
node = np.array([[1, 12, 0], [2, 8, 10], [3, 0, 10], [4, 24, 10]])

for a in range(0, NELEM):
    n1, n2 = con[a]
    x1 = node[n1-1, 1]
    x2 = node[n2-1, 1]
    dx = x2 - x1
```

You could do this in a single line using array indexing instead of a loop, it will also be faster.

```
node[con[:,1]-1,1] - node[con[:,0]-1,1]
 # [-12  -4  12  -8  16]
```